Why is the rest in the definition of a divergence function $O(|d\xi|^3)$ and not $o(|d\xi|^2)$?
I am reading Shun-ichi Amari's "Information Geometry and Its Applications" and on page 10, it defines divergences as functions that satisfy:

$\forall P, Q,\quad D[P:Q] \ge 0$
$D[P:Q] = 0 \iff P=Q$
In local coordiantes, they have have a Taylor expansion of the form:
$$D[\xi_p:\xi_p+d\xi] = \frac{1}{2}\sum g_{ij}(\xi_p)d\xi_id\xi_j + O(|d\xi|^3).$$

My question is: why is the rest of the approximation $O(|d\xi|^3)$ rather than $o(|d\xi|^2)$? What do we gain by imposing this stronger condition? Is this related to the fact that a divergence defines a Riemannian metric on the manifold of probability measures? Does this taylor approximation hold for Riemannian metrics in general? And if not, why impose it on divrgences?
